# FPDF Library replaces ' with &#039;

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am not sure if anybody else has noticed this. but i am using FPDF library to generate PDF documents. But I just noticed if I pass a value with a `'` in it, the `'` is replaced with `&#039;`

For example the one value being passed is CD's but it is shown after the output as `CD&#039;s` anybody have an idea on what is causing this?

I use `$pdf->Cell(0,4,"Name: ".$name,0,1,"C");` to add the string, but I have also tried using `$pdf->Cell(0,4,"Name: ".htmlspecialchars_decode($name),0,1,"C");` aswell but still getting the same result.

Any ideas are welcome & appreciated. :)

Comment: Sounds like an issue with character encoding: `fpdf` cannot work with unicode, use `tcpdf` instead which is the unicode aware fork. The `'` you cite most likely isn't really a `'` but a character that looks very similar and is not contained in the 8bit range `fcpdf` assumes. It is very often seen that "exotic" characters are used instead of simple apostrophs. You can easily check that by using a `hexeditor` to look at the coding of that string.

Comment: @arkascha switching to `tcpdf` would then mean re-developing all the PDF coding would it not? I am not sure if their functions work the same?

Comment: Why don't you simply take a look at their site and documentation? And give it a try? As said: `tcpdf` is a fork of `fpdf` with the goal to implement unicode handling. So the usage is basically identical, except for the obvious differences required.